# How to reuse condition blocks on htaccess so I don't need to write it again for a new rule?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am writing a blog with Wordpress and I have a website with Codeigniter and both are on the same server. I am setting the routing for them and I have this rules on my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(ico|js|css|jpg|png|gif|html|ico?g)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*) blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(ico|js|css|jpg|png|gif|html|ico?g)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But note that most of the conditions are the same, because I need practically the same for both rewritings.

If I remove the second block of conditions and skip directly to the second `RewriteRule` I get a server error. Is it possible to group conditions for different rules (and eventually add some extra condition as I did with the first rule)?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(ico|js|css|jpg|png|gif|html|ico?g)$

RewriteRule ^blog/.* blog/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I had trouble capturing the `.*` for the blog part, so that's uncaptured. Don't think it really needs to be anyway.